# Joint plot for groupby datas on seaborn

Tags: pandas, seaborn, subplot, facet-grid, jointplot

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
In[1]: df.head()
Out[1]:
dataset  x     y
   1     56   45
   1     31   67
   7     22   85
   2     90   45
   2     15   42
```

There are about 4000 more rows. x and y is grouped by the datasets. I am trying to plot a jointplot for **each** dataset separately using seaborn. This is what I can come up so far:

```
import seaborn as sns

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="dataset", col_wrap=3)
g.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, x="x", y="y", color = "#7db4a2")
g.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, x="x", color = "#7db4a2")
g.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, y="y", color = "#7db4a2")
g.add_legend();
```

but there are all overlapped. How do I make a proper jointplot for each dataset in  a subplot? Thank you in advanced and cheers!

Comment: Update to seaborn 0.11.2 and use `seaborn.jointplot`: `sns.jointplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='dataset')`. Also a FacetGrid is a figure-level plot, there isn't currently an option to have sub-figures.

Comment: Hmm. How do you suggest I should tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on your *dataset* column, then use `sns.jointgrid()`, and then finally add your scatter plot and KDE plot to the jointgrid.

Here is an example using a random seed generator with numpy. I made three "datasets"  and random x,y values. See the [Seaborn `jointgrid` documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html) for ways to customize  colors, etc.

```
### Build an example dataset
np.random.seed(seed=1)
ds = (np.arange(3)).tolist()*10
x = np.random.randint(100, size=(60)).tolist()
y = np.random.randint(20, size=(60)).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(ds, x, y), columns=["ds", "x", "y"])

### The plots
for _ds, group in df.groupby('ds'):
    group = group.copy()
    g = sns.JointGrid(data=group, x='x', y='y')
    g.plot(sns.scatterplot, sns.kdeplot)
```

[image]